# why is the keypress not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript

Good day, the following code works on desktop but not mobile.  When I switch to keyup or keydown instead of keypress it doesn't work anywhere.

```
function attribUppercase(e)
{
    var charInput = e.keyCode;
    if((charInput >= 97) && (charInput <= 122)) { // lowercase
        if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey) { // no modifier key
        var newChar = charInput - 32;
        var start = e.target.selectionStart;
        var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
        e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, start) + String.fromCharCode(newChar) + e.target.value.substring(end);
        e.target.setSelectionRange(start+1, start+1);
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("attrib-108-0");
    if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
    document.getElementById("attrib-108-0").addEventListener("keypress", attribUppercase, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On which device did you tried your code ? As JS is interpreted differently on each device, the `keypress`/`keydown`/`keyup` may not be implemented since it rarely used on mobile devices

Comment: The `keypress` event has been marked as **deprecated** (see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) and as such most mobile browsers simply has never supported it since the beginning of iPhones and Andriod. Use `keyup` or `keydown` instead.

Comment: Also note that `event.keyCode` is also **deprecated** and therefore does not work on more most mobile browsers. Use `event.key` instead. But do note, the codes returned by `.key` and `.keyCode` are not the same